# Google Cpu profiler

Tags: profiling, gperf

I want to try google cpu profiler to analyze hotspots on a C project as an alternative to gprof so to find any differencies because i am not convinced about the accuracy gprof provides, but as  i am now introducing myself to these tools i am confused about the way i should link the libraries to my program and then execute it in order to take the results for the profiling.

Keep in mind i compile the code through a makefile so i guess flags should be added there for the linking but whatever efforts i made ended in failure.

I downloaded gperf and related packages from synaptics package manager as well as installed gperf through the command line with sudo but i cant find a way to link my program to the appropriate libraries.

Any help would be appreciated, thank you.

Comment: + Does your C project spend much time doing I/O? CPU profilers will not see that.

Comment: No, there is minimum i/o handling in my project. Gprof provided meaningful and reasonable results , i though need verification from another profiling tool just to be sure. Tried Vtune but having issues with drivers prevented me from taking results , found interesting infromation about google tool and i thought i should give it a try.